# Getting large profile picture from Facebook Graph-API

Tags: kotlin, facebook-graph-api

I am building a Kotlin app and am using FirebaseAuth for login. I activated Facebook login via Firebase and it works fine. My problem is that the created Firebase user's photoUrl: (`https://graph.facebook.com/<UserId>/picture`) is pointing to a tiny version of it's Facebook profile picture, instead of a normal sized one.
I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52099896/13674106. The Google part of this answer worked perfectly for me, but in the Facebook case I am now getting a default avatar image (in the right resolution). My code looks like this:

```
    fun handleSignInSucceeded(dataIntent: Intent?) {
        val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(dataIntent)

        // For new created users, check if a photo is available from the auth provider
        if (response?.isNewUser == true) {
            // All users have a default FirebaseAuth provider data - we want to check which is the
            // other one
            currentUser.value?.providerData
                ?.find { it.providerId != FirebaseAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID }?.apply {
                    val photoUrl = when (providerId) {
                        GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID ->
                            photoUrl.toString().replace("s96-c", "s400-c").toUri()
                        FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID ->
                            photoUrl.toString().plus("?type=large").toUri()
                        else -> null
                    }
                    photoUrl?.let { updatePhotoUri(it, false) }
                }
        }
    }

fun updatePhotoUri(photoUrl: Uri, uploadToStorage: Boolean = true): Task<Void>? {
        val profileUpdates = UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()

        return if (uploadToStorage)    ...
        else updateProfile(profileUpdates.setPhotoUri(photoUrl).build())
    }

private fun updateProfile(profileUpdates: UserProfileChangeRequest): Task<Void>? {
        return currentUser.value?.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
            ?.addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.")
                    _currentUser.value = firebaseAuth.currentUser
                }
            }
    }
```

Where `_currentUser` is a private `MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser?>` shadowed by a public `LiveData<FirebaseUser?>` called `user` which is binded to my ImageView on  the fragment:

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_profile_picture"
                    ...
                    app:userPhotoSrc="@{profileViewModel.user}" />
```

Where `userPhotoSrc` is implemented by the following `BindingAdapter` using `Glide`:

```
@BindingAdapter("userPhotoSrc")
fun ImageView.setUserPhotoSrc(user: FirebaseUser?) {
    Glide.with(context)
        .load(user?.photoUrl)
        .circleCrop()
        .fallback(R.drawable.ic_profile_black_24)
        .into(this)
}
```

I checked in debug and the value of `user?.photoUrl` at that point is `https://graph.facebook.com/<UserId>/picture?type=large` as expected.
I found this thread: [Retrieving Default Image All Url Profile Picture from Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49917726/13674106), Which shows a problem similar to mine, but according to the answers there, my code should work by now. I also tried to use the `height` parameter instead of `type`, like stated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50710161/13674106, But I got the same result.

Please help me solve it,
Omer

Comment: Try if appending the access token to the profile picture URL helps. Facebook is in the process of making that a requirement, it is supposed to go live for all app on 2020-10-24, but with a newly created app id(?) it might apply before already. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture

Comment: That worked, thanks! I didn't try that because getting the tiny image kept on working so I it's weird that it is an authentication problem. Do you have an idea why it worked? Just so I can understand it better.